# In Linux shell bash script, how to print to a file at the same line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In Linux shell bash script, how to print to a file at the same line ?

At each iteration,

I used

```
 echo "$variable1"  >> file_name, 

 echo "$variable2"  >> file_name,
```

but echo insert a newline so that it becomes

```
 $v1

 $v2
```

not

```
     $v1 \tab  $v2
```

"\c" cannot eat newline.

this post 
[BASH shell script echo to output on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228807/bash-shell-script-echo-to-output-on-same-line)

does not help .

thanks

Answer (score 7):

After wading through that question, I've decided that what you're looking for is `echo -n`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for a single tab in between the variables, then printf is a good choice.

```
printf '%s\t%s' "$v1" "$v2" >> file_name
```

If you want it exactly like your example where the tab is padded with a space on both sides:

```
printf '%s \t %s' "$v1" "$v2" >> file_name
```

Answer (score 2):

few options there:

1. `echo -n foo bar` It's simple, but may not work on some old UNIX systems like HP-UX or SunOS. Instead the "-n" will be printed as well as the rest of the arguments followed by new line.
2. `echo -e "foo bar\c"` . The `\c` has meaning: "*produce no further output*". I don't like this solution personally, but some UNIX wizards use it.
3. `printf %b "foo bar"` I like this solution the most. It's quite portable as well flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Use `echo -n` to trim the newline. See if that works