# Why is Jenkins shell scripting giving other results than for the same command compared to my local results?

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to capture the response of an http request in a variable. The following question gave me the perfect solution to this ([How to evaluate http response codes from bash/shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220301/how-to-evaluate-http-response-codes-from-bash-shell-script)). When I execute this command locally

```
response=$(curl --write-out '%{http_code}' --silent --output /dev/null http://localhost:8082/url)
echo $response
```

It gives me the wanted http code (e.g. 400). However in Jenkins I execute the same command, but it gives me an empty response:

```
sh '''#!/bin/bash
      DOCKER_RESPONSE=$(curl --write-out '%{http_code}' --silent --output /dev/null http://localhost:8002/route?json={})
      while [[ $DOCKER_RESPONSE != 200 ]]
      do
        sleep 1
        echo "$DOCKER_RESPONSE"
        DOCKER_RESPONSE=$(curl --write-out '%{http_code}' --silent --output /dev/null http://localhost:8002/route?json={})
      done
                            
'''
```

Comment: If you want to have the output of `sh` command, you have to use `def shell_output = sh returnStdout: true, script: ``` ... ``` `. Otherwise it's possible that `"200" != 200` as one is string and another is number.

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing groovy syntex with bash , it has to be like below

```
node {
    stage('one') {
        sh """
          res=\$(curl --write-out '%{http_code}' --silent --output /dev/null https://google.com)
          echo \$res
          while [[ \$res != '301' ]]
          do
            sleep 1
            echo \$res
            res=\$(curl --write-out '%{http_code}' --silent --output /dev/null https://google.com)
          done
        """
    }
}
```

and The output will be

[image]

Comment: The OP used a non-expanding syntax with three single quotes and so they have no need to escape the `$` character.